# How to capture user's click action when clicking on notifications

Tags: c++, windows, notifications

Currently, I want to show a balloon notification on Windows, then I want to **capture the action** when a user clicks **on the balloon notification**.
Then I will do another action after capturing this action.

How can I do that?
And can I do that on all of the Windows platforms (from Windows 7 to Windows 10)?

Comment: How are you doing the 1st part (_"... show a balloon notification ..."_) ?

Comment: What action do you want to capture exactly? If you just want to know when the tooltip disappears, look for the `TTN_POP` notification.

Comment: @M10 Are you using `Shell_NotifyIcon()` to display the balloon? If so, then you use `NOTIFYICONDATA::hWnd` and `NOTIFICATION::uCallbackMessage` to receive notifications: "*The system uses [uCallbackMessage]  to send notification messages to the window identified in hWnd. These notification messages are sent when a mouse event or hover occurs in the bounding rectangle of the icon, when the icon is selected or activated with the keyboard, **or when those actions occur in the balloon notification**.*"

Comment: @RichardCritten I use Shell_NotifyIcon() to display the balloon.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I want to show a balloon notification with a direction. Then when a user clicks this notification, I will open a webpage.
Therefore, I want to capture the action that the user clicks on the balloon notification to do this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I want to know when a user clicks on ballon notification (capture user's click action), then I will open a webpage or I can do another thing.
Could you please explain more details?

Comment: @M10 see the answer I just posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said in comments that you are using `Shell_NotifyIcon()` to display the balloon. The answer to your question is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyiconw):

> As of Windows XP ([Shell32.dll version 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776779(v=vs.85))), if a user passes the mouse pointer over an icon with which a balloon notification is associated, the Shell sends the following messages:
>
> - NIN_BALLOONSHOW. Sent when the balloon is shown (balloons are queued).
> - NIN_BALLOONHIDE. Sent when the balloon disappears. For example, when the icon is deleted. This message is not sent if the balloon is dismissed because of a timeout or if the user clicks the mouse.
> - As of Windows 7, NIN_BALLOONHIDE  is also sent when a notification with the [NIIF_RESPECT_QUIET_TIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataw) flag set attempts to display during quiet time (a user's first hour on a new computer). In that case, the balloon is never displayed at all.
> - NIN_BALLOONTIMEOUT. Sent when the balloon is dismissed because of a timeout.
> - **NIN_BALLOONUSERCLICK. Sent when the balloon is dismissed because the user clicked the mouse.**
>
> In addition to those messages, as of Windows Vista (Shell32.dll version 6.0.6), if a user passes the mouse pointer over an icon with which a balloon notification is associated, the Windows Vista Shell also adds the following messages:
>
> - NIN_POPUPOPEN. Sent when the user hovers the cursor over an icon to indicate that the richer pop-up UI should be used in place of a standard textual tooltip.
> - NIN_POPUPCLOSE. Sent when a cursor no longer hovers over an icon to indicate that the rich pop-up UI should be closed.
>
> Regardless of the operating system version, you can select which way the Shell should behave by calling `Shell_NotifyIcon` with *dwMessage* set to `NIM_SETVERSION`. **Set the `uVersion` member of the NOTIFYICONDATA structure pointed to by *lpdata* to indicate whether you want Windows 2000, Windows Vista, or pre-version 5.0 (Windows 95) behavior**.
>
> **Note The messages discussed above are not conventional Windows messages. They are sent as the *lParam* value of the application-defined message that is specified in the `uCallbackMessage` member of the NOTIFYICONDATA structure pointed to by *lpdata*, when `Shell_NotifyIcon` is called with the `NIM_ADD` flag set in *dwMessage*.**

So, to receive these messages, you need to specify an HWND and Callback message ID in the [`NOTIFYICONDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataw) struct when calling `Shell_NotifyIcon()` with `dwMessage` set to `NIM_ADD` or `NIM_MODIFY`:

> hWnd
>   Type: `HWND`
>   **A handle to the window that receives notifications associated with an icon in the notification area**.
>
> ...
>
> uCallbackMessage
>   Type: `UINT`
>   An application-defined message identifier. **The system uses this identifier to send notification messages to the window identified in `hWnd`**. These notification messages are sent when a mouse event or hover occurs in the bounding rectangle of the icon, when the icon is selected or activated with the keyboard, or **when those actions occur in the balloon notification**.
>
> When the `uVersion` member is either 0 or NOTIFYICON_VERSION, the *wParam* parameter of the message contains the identifier of the taskbar icon in which the event occurred. This identifier can be 32 bits in length. **The *lParam* parameter holds the mouse or keyboard message associated with the event**. For example, when the pointer moves over a taskbar icon, *lParam* is set to WM_MOUSEMOVE.
>
> When the `uVersion` member is NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4, applications continue to receive notification events in the form of application-defined messages through the `uCallbackMessage` member, but the interpretation of the *lParam* and *wParam* parameters of that message is changed as follows:
>
> - **LOWORD(lParam) contains notification events, such as NIN_BALLOONSHOW, NIN_POPUPOPEN, or WM_CONTEXTMENU**.
> - HIWORD(lParam) contains the icon ID. Icon IDs are restricted to a length of 16 bits.
> - GET_X_LPARAM(wParam) returns the X anchor coordinate for notification events NIN_POPUPOPEN, NIN_SELECT, NIN_KEYSELECT, and all mouse messages between WM_MOUSEFIRST and WM_MOUSELAST. If any of those messages are generated by the keyboard, *wParam* is set to the upper-left corner of the target icon. For all other messages, *wParam* is undefined.
> - GET_Y_LPARAM(wParam) returns the Y anchor coordinate for notification events and messages as defined for the X anchor.
>
> ...
>
> **If you set the `NIF_INFO` flag in the `uFlags` member, the balloon-style notification is used. For more discussion of these notifications, see [Balloon tooltips](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/Controls/using-tooltip-contro)**.

So, to answer your question, in the WndProc for the HWND that you specify in the `NOTIFYICONDATA::hWnd` field, you would look for the message ID you specify in the `NOTIFYICONDATA::uCallbackMessage` field, and then look for the `NIN_BALLOONUSERCLICK` notification in the message's `lParam` or `LOWORD(lParam)` value, depending on how you set the `NOTIFYICONDATA::uVersion` field.

Comment: The balloon's message stays in the Windows 11 notification area after the balloon has timed out. Is there a way to get notifications when the user clicks there?